# Intermittent animation on mouseover

Tags: jquery

I am trying to animate a border on mouseover:

```
$('.feature').mouseover(function(){
    border = $(this).find('.features_icon img');
    border.stop(true,true).animate({ borderColor: "#add423"  }, 'slow'); 
});
$('.feature').mouseout(function(){
    border = $(this).find('.features_icon img');
    border.animate({ borderColor: "transparent"  }, 'slow'); 
});
```

But when I hover over the .feature element too quickly, the animate effect doesn't occur, it just shows it instead. I am assuming there is something wrong here, perhaps the stop() function. How is this done properly to make it animate correctly?

Comment: You could do this with CSS, might be easier.

Comment: can you share your html... also have a look at css3 animations

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3r315wqx/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in using [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) as they are triggered when you move the cursor to a child element... so try with [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)(or the shortcut [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/))

like

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.feature').mouseenter(function () {
        var border = $(this).find('.features_icon img');
        border.stop(true, true).animate({
            borderColor: "#add423"
        }, 'slow');
    });
    $('.feature').mouseleave(function () {
        var border = $(this).find('.features_icon img');
        border.animate({
            borderColor: "transparent"
        }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3r315wqx/)

But a [css3 animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) will be much easier like

```
.features_icon img {
    border-width:5px;
    border-style:solid;
    transition : border 1s ease-out; 
}

.feature:hover .features_icon img {
    border-color:#add423;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5n31xan3/)

Comment: But is transition that browser friendly?

Comment: @user2909486 you need to look at the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#Browser_compatibility)... I think it will work fine in IE >= 10